# Visual Studio 11 Ultimate Static Analysis Shows No Output

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, static-analysis

So Microsoft released a trial version of Visual Studio 11 Ultimate Developer Preview. I decided to try out the static code analysis feature.

I successfully updated my solution to 2011 and get my project file to build.

However when I try to run the 'Run Code Analysis For Solution' it then proceeds to simply build the solution/project but display no output in the code analysis window (even if I've hacked the code to make sure it should show some errors).

I did have Visual Studio 2010 previously installed and I wonder if that's affecting it?

Any help or anyone ran into similar issue?

*EDIT:
I made a sample project and in it the code analysis works... I'm not sure what I'm missing from my old migrated project to enable it. (I've done the obvious and enabled Static Analysis in the configuration properties menu)

Answer (score 0):

First check which build toolset do you use.
For upgraded project it is Visual Studio 2010 by default.

However when I did similar exercise with my project it didn't compile after switching to VC11 compiler - there were some issues with include paths I had to resolve.

Comment: I believe I had the toolset to the latest one. V110 ?

Comment: Sorry, could you please confirm that under Configuration Properties of your project in General page on Platform Toolset you see that Visual Studio 2011 (v110) is set for **all** configurations?